# Finding the list of saved WIFI SSIDs on an iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ssid, captivenetwork

I understand you can get the current connected Wi-Fi network using the CaptiveNetwork interface.  I also understand that Apple has cracked down on scanning for networks.  What I need is to be able to read the list of 'stored' SSIDs that the phone connects automatically to.

I am attempting to use the Wi-Fi network as a sort of location trigger, that changes functionality when the user connects to his 'home' network.  Using CaptiveNetwork I can get the current network and allow them to save that name, but can I get the list of saved networks so the user can set locations without having to be at each one during setup?